# Display MySQL table column in a dropdown menu in a React front-end with NodeJS backend

Tags: mysql, node.js, reactjs

I want to know how to display a table in MySQL table data in a dropdown menu. When clicking the drop-down menu should be loaded the data in the MySQL table.

This is my front-end code.

**Main.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
export class Main extends Component {

    render() {
        return (
           <select type="select" >
            <option selected>Select ID</option>
            <option >CM0468</option>
            <option>GM0057</option>
            <option>PU0171</option>
            <option>KA0048</option>
            <option>NU0003</option>               
          </select>
       );
    }
}
export default Main
```

**This is my database.js**

```
var mysql = require('mysql');

var con = mysql.createConnection({
    host: "localhost",
    user: "",
    password: "",
    database: ""
});

con.connect(function(err) {
    if (err) throw err;
    con.query("SELECT * FROM siteid", function (err, result, fields) {
       if (err) throw err;
       console.log(result);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two pieces of the puzzle but are just missing the bit in the middle.

There is a means of retrieving the data from the database and there is also a UI to display the data. You now need a means of passing the data from the `node` side (the server) to the front end (React).

This can be done in various ways but a simple way would be to spin up a web server using something like [express](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express) and add a `GET` endpoint that will return your query data.

Then, on the front end, you will add an API request using something like [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) to retrieve the data from your server.

Once you have the data, you can loop over it and populate your `select` with the options from the database